# Dockerfile vs docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What's the relation between `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files?

Looks like I can build any Linux setup using `Dockerfile` using `FROM`, `RUN` (`apt-get` etc. and `CMD` commands. But it seems, this is not much reusable (I can reuse the whole image, but the services are hardcdoded and not reusable by other projects).

Shall I use both of the files on new projects?

Let's say I want to have regular LAMP stack:

- Linux OS (`debian:wheezy`)
- Apache web server (`httpd:2.2`)
- MySQL (`mariadb`)
- PHP (`php:5.6`)

running together as on one, regular machine.

And in a dir on my host system:

- volume for app source files
- vhost config file
- apache logs
- persistent data in db

I prefer using official, base repos and images, not the pre-configured all-in-ones.

How the config files are supposed to look like in this case?

I'm using `docker-compose` v.1.8.1 and `docker` v. 1.12.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 23):

`Dockerfile`:

- is a recipe for a Docker Image
- only supports portable options (others options have to be specified at container run time)

`docker-compose.yaml`:

- is a recipe for a group of running services
- supports overriding portable options that were defined in the `Dockerfile`
- supports non-portable options
- supports creating and configuring networks and volumes
- can also configure the build of an Image by using `build:`

It is common to use both together.

A `Dockerfile` is almost always used to create a custom image. Some images might be used to run services (long running processes), but some images might be used to run short-lived interactive processes (like running unit tests).

`docker-compose.yaml` is useful when you want to run one or more services.

Comment: And what are portable options?

Comment: Portable options are options that behave the same way on all hosts. For exposing setting an environment variable using `ENV`. A non portable option would be something like a host bind mount, where the directory needs to exist on the host for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been trying to understand, if I want to run, for example, an nginx container with specific options (port mappings and volumes), do I specify that using a Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, or something else (like a bash script). If I understand this answer correctly, I can rule out a Dockerfile for such a task.

Answer (score 15):

**Docker** creates isolated machine (container). Each container contains only one process (Apache or Mysql or another); And Dockerfile defines how to build a image.

**Docker compose** allows run, links and configure the **bunch** of containers together.

In your case apache needs to know "where" a mysql. And mysql needs to be waked up before you run apache container.

`Dockerfile` defines how to create app image. App image contains you application and web-browser.

```
FROM apache:php5.6

ADD /src /var/www/awesome_project #add a project src code
ADD /config/apache/awesome_project.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/ # add a configuration
# make any things
```

Then you need to build image `docker build my_app:latest .`

At this point you have created image, and you need to run app and links it to db

you have 2 ways to do this:

1) *Native docker approach*. you run db container

`docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest`

and after you need to run app container (image was created before)

`docker run --name my_app --link some-mysql:mysql -P -d my_app`

at this point we have worked application. Bit this simple thing cause us make 2 long command. If you need copy application to another machine you need to repeat this command exactly.

2) *docker-compose way* allows create a configuration for running the containers. It described how exactly run containers.

Simple `docker-compose.yml` config illustrate this approach

```
db:
   image: mysql
   environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

app:
   image: my_app:latest
   ports:
    - 80:80
   depends_on:
    - db
   environment:
    # Database
    - DB_USER_NAME=root
    - DB_USER_PASSWORD=root
```

This config allows you run 2 container together, links and configure them.

This is very easy example. and pros of using docker compose not apparent, but if you have 5+ containers it is too hard to run them together without compose.

Comment: So the `Dockerfile` is not needed at all? How do I define the whole stack described in my question by just using `docker-compose.yml`? Is Dockerfile an older way of Docker configuration or a way suitable for creating low level images, like distro clones?

Comment: you need a Dockerfile. Dockerfile defines how to create certain docker image (at low level). 
Docker compose defines how to run, link,configure containers (from images) together

Comment: Could you please provide complete example of both files, regarding the setup from my question?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I still don't see where is php and Apache attached. Why `FROM apache:php5.6`?

Comment: In this example image `my_app` contains src code, php and apache, because base image is `apache:php5.6`

Comment: So if I want to create my own clean image, I have to use `FROM debian:wheezy` and `apt-get install apache2 php5` etc then use it in compose file? How can I have Apache (`httpd:2.2` image from hub) and PHP (`php:5.6` image) linked together in `docker-compose.yml`? I can learn on examples of Dockerfiles on hub.docker.com, but I don't know any source for similar examples for compose files.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake image `apache:5.6` does't exist. You need use `image: php:apache` from [official repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/php/tags/) It is official php image with php and apache in one image.

Comment: Looks like `php:apache` is just the environment for PHP as Apache module. I still need to use `debian` and `httpd` images too.

Comment: Better take a look at this tutorial ... http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html

Answer (score 7):

It's fundamentally about a separation of concerns and a simple way to conceive this is by thinking in terms of **what** vrs **how**.

Dockerfile defines **what** goes on within a container.

Docker-compose.yml defines **how** that container is run within a host. This is why they say in docs - "services are just containers in production".

The container doesn't care how or where it is run, its just concerned with what it is running. The host doesn't care about **what** it is running only **how** it is run .e.g. multiple instances, this much RAM, that much CPU, make sure you start this service before that one, etc.

So we create two separate configuration docs for each of these purposes.